# Why can't I enter an open source project on my Careers profile if I don't have write access?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, open-source

I contribute to a few open source projects for which I don't have VCS write access (the main developer prefers patches instead or I simply don't contribute that often) so I can't use the built-in sf.net importer on the Careers site, but I'd like to list them anyway. However, the project form doesn't allow me to use the sf.net url and recommends me to use the sf.net project importer.

Comment: That's the point, I can't, it "complains" about sf.net prefix. Of course, I could use an URL shortener but I don't think that's the way to do that.

Comment: Ah, missed a detail again. :-)